# Python regular expression execution gets stuck

Tags: python, regex, substring, python-re

I am working on a project where I am trying to match a string to python regular expression pattern but the execution gets stuck in an infinite loop and execution is stuck. Here is the code:

```
import re

txt = 'a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a a.:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a .a:a b.:a b.:a b.:a b.:a b.:a b.:a b.:a b.:a b.:a b.:a b.:a b.:a b.:a b.:a b.:a b.:a ..:a ..:a ..:a ..:a ..:a ..:a ..:a ..:a ..:a ..:a ..:a ..:a ..:a ..:a ..:a ..:a ..:a ..:a'
pat = re.compile('(?:a[^ :]*:[^ ]*)+()(?: [^:]+:[^ ]*){,}?(?: .a[^ :]*:[^ ]*)+()(?: [^:]+:[^ ]*){,}?(?: b[^ :]*:[^ ]*){7,7}?()(?: [^:]+:[^ ]*){,}?(?: .b[^ :]*:[^ ]*)+')
x = pat.search(txt)
print(x)
```

Any pointers on how to solve this problem will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have nested quantifiers and are therefore prone to [**Catastrophic Backtracking**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).
See the first construct of your expression (it applies to the others as well):

```
(?:a[^ :]*:[^ ]*)+     # star inside of plus
#       ^^^     ^^^
```

One important brick of a good expression is that the regex engine fails faster if there's no match. With nested quantifiers, the engine looks back and forth a million times.

Comment: Thank you for the article. I suspected that to be happening as well. Sorry, I can't mark your answer as acceptable owing to low reputation score. Thanks a lot.